# Open a Bootstrap modal via a plain function not a jQuery object method call

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I can open Bootstrap's [modal dialogs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal) via a *method* on a jQuery object:

```
$('#myModal').modal(options)
```

However in my code I have already the plain DOM `Element` of the modal `div` retrieved as

```
var myModal = document.querySelector("#myModal")
```

But this `Element` object does not feature Bootstrap's `modal` method. Is there a way to use this Element object and *not* to invoke the jQuery selector? So is it possible to call  Bootstrap's `modal` code as a plain *function* taking the Element as a parameter? I am thinking of something like

```
modal(myModal, options)
```

Any pointers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s no way to do something like `modal(myModal, options)` as Bootstrap (like all plugins) extends the jQuery function prototype.

When Bootstrap’s JavaScript first runs, it extends jQuery’s prototype function with code similar to `$.fn.modal` and then Bootstrap assigns the modal functionality to that new jQuery function.

Now, if you already have the modal element assigned to a JavaScript variable, then it is possible to use that variable as the jQuery selector and show or toggle or hide or whatever operation you want. I don’t know if there would be any advantage to do so, but it would be possible.

In the demo below, I’m using JavaScript to open a modal when the page loads:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    const myModalElement = document.getElementById('myModal');

    $(myModalElement).modal('show');

    /* $('#myModal').modal('show'); */
</script>
```